# Strange holes appearing in laminate flooring

Tags: laminate-floor

I saw these strange holes appearing in my laminate flooring (see the picture), I think it has to be a result of some bug, is there any way how to treat this or do I need to replace the laminate floor?

[image]

Comment: Those may be from termites.  I'd pull that up and look underneath.

Comment: Only in the trim, (which it looks like form the picture)  or in the actual flooring?

Comment: The trim has just a thin veneer that termites can chew through. The laminate has a thicker harder surface they don't like.  That's why I'm thinking termites.  Anyway Op has to have a look under.

Comment: @Ecnerwal only in the trim, thanks for advice I will look under it.